# Read The Docs : How to specify where your sources are

Tags: python, indexing, python-sphinx, read-the-docs

I am working on a python package with folder structure

```
- my_package
    - setup.py
    - docs
         -source
               - conf.py
               - index.rst
    - my_package
        (python modules)
```

index.rst looks like:

```
My package
==========

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2
   :caption: Contents:


Indices and tables
------------------

* :ref:`genindex`
* :ref:`modindex`
* :ref:`search`


Description
------------

Blablabla
```

conf.py was generated by sphinx, and using all defaults values except at the beginning with:

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../..'))
```

Following tutorials, I ended up compiling on my machine sphinx documentation with the following command line:

```
sphinx-apidoc -f -o source/ ../my_package/ && make html
```

This works fine and generate a full HTML documentation, with suitable indexes and module index.

Once my github repos linked to read the docs, the build succeed, the documentation is generated. The index looks fine, with the content of index.rst properly displayed. But the index is empty and the module index does not exist ("sorry, this page does not exist yet"). The search tool find only with is part of index.rst and nothing else. Feels like the source and related docstrings were never found.

I looked at the build output, but nothing caught my eye.

Comment: You need to configure your RTD project to install your package on RTD. See https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#my-project-isn-t-building-with-autodoc

Comment: got link to builds on RTD? Got a reproducible example? Otherwise there ain't no way anyone can guess what's wrong.

Comment: @StevePiercy actually, I turned out to have an issue with my setup.py, so the installation was failing. After the fix, it worked. I deleted my comment about this not working.